# Falla en Encoding.UTF-8 al Exportar de GridView a .TXT en C#

Tags: c#, txt

He tratado de establecer el formato UTF-8 a un conjunto de datos que requiero pasar a un documento de texto .txt

Los datos los presentó en la gridview con la siguiente estructura:

```
clna1 | Clna2|   Clna3    | Clna4   |  Clna5   |  Clna6     |  Clna6
______________________________________________________________________________
02    |  CC  | 1006453797 | 153609  |  1800000 | 30/01/2020 | CAILE NUÑEZ SAIDA SILENIA
______________________________________________________________________________
```

el objetivo es que esos datos se incluyan en el archivo delimitados por comas, para esto empleo el siguiente metodo:

```
 protected void ButtonGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string txt = string.Empty;
            //Default
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewDefault.Rows)
            {
                foreach (TableCell redatos in row.Cells)
                {
                    txt += redatos.Text + ",";
                }
                txt += "\r\n";
            }
            //Datos 
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewDatos.Rows)
            {
                foreach (TableCell datos in row.Cells)
                {
                    txt += datos.Text + ",";
                }
            txt += "\r\n";
            }

            }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=RelacionDatos_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".txt");
            Response.Output.Write(txt,Encoding.UTF8);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

con este método logro incluir los datos en el documento .txt, pero me arroja los datos de manera incorrecta, logró interpretar que no me toma la notación utf-8 aun especificando. Como puedo modificar para que los datos pasen de manera correcta.

Datos de Muestra:

```
02,CC,1006453797,153609,1800000,30/01/2020,CAILE NU&#209;EZ SAIDA SILENIA,
```

Comment: mira en estas respuestas de Stack Overflow en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138612/c-sharp-save-datagridview-to-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La codificación utf8 no es el problema, la información que estas extrayendo del celda aun sigue en código Html, puedes usar el metodo **System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode** para decodificar el string de forma correcta:

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=RelacionDatos_" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".txt");
        Response.Output.Write(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(txt), Encoding.UTF8);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```